# divide a range(n,n+2000) into chunks of size j.

Tags: python

How to divide a range(n,n+2000) into chunks of size j.
The output should look like [0,500],[500,1000],[1000,1500],[1500,2000].
But if range(n,n+7864) , then how do we divide them into roughly equal size chunks.

Attempted code:

```
for a in range(1,500): 
    if (last<500):
        last=a+500 list.append([a,last]);
        a=last; 
    elif(last>500):
        list.append([list[len(list)-2][1],last element])
```

Comment: What is fixed: the size of the chunks or the number of chunks?

Comment: Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: Size is fixed such as j=500.

Comment: for a in range(1,500):                                            if (last<500):last=a+500
     list.append([a,last]);
  a=last;
 elif(last>500):
     list.append([list[len(list)-2][1],last element])

Comment: Please edit your post to include that :) Also, this is python 2, correct?

Comment: Hi alKid Python 2.7.3

Comment: I am trying to edit but its not taking my edits

Comment: @mparida What is your expected output for `(0, 7864, 500)`?

Answer (score 4):

Straightforward using `zip`:

```
def range_sequence(start, stop, step):
    return zip(range(start, stop, step), range(start+step, stop+step, step))
```

Result:

```
In [4]: list(range_sequence(0, 2000, 500))
Out[4]: [(0, 500), (500, 1000), (1000, 1500), (1500, 2000)]
```

Note that this might include an unwanted element at the end:

```
In [5]: list(range_sequence(0, 7864, 500))
Out[5]: 
[(0, 500),
 (500, 1000),
 (1000, 1500),
 (1500, 2000),
 (2000, 2500),
 (2500, 3000),
 (3000, 3500),
 (3500, 4000),
 (4000, 4500),
 (4500, 5000),
 (5000, 5500),
 (5500, 6000),
 (6000, 6500),
 (6500, 7000),
 (7000, 7500),
 (7500, 8000)]
```

the `(7500, 8000)` pair might not be what you want. If you simply want to stop at `(7000, 7500)` you can change the `stop+step` into simply `stop`.
If the last pair should be `(7500, 7864)` then you have to do something a bit more compex:

```
def range_sequence(start, stop, step):
    result = list(zip(range(start, stop, step), range(start+step, stop, step))
    if (stop - start) % step != 0:
        last_fst_elem = result[-1][-1] if result else start
        result.append((last_fst_elem, stop))
    return result
```

Result:

```
In [15]: range_sequence(0, 7864, 500)
Out[15]: 
[(0, 500),
 (500, 1000),
 (1000, 1500),
 (1500, 2000),
 (2000, 2500),
 (2500, 3000),
 (3000, 3500),
 (3500, 4000),
 (4000, 4500),
 (4500, 5000),
 (5000, 5500),
 (5500, 6000),
 (6000, 6500),
 (6500, 7000),
 (7000, 7500),
 (7500, 7864)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator function:

```
>>> import math
def solve(start, end, sep):
    prev = start
    for _ in xrange(int(math.ceil((end-start)/float(sep)))):
        _next = prev + sep
        yield [prev, min(_next, end)]
        prev = _next
...         
>>> list(solve(0, 7864, 500))
[[0, 500], [500, 1000], [1000, 1500], [1500, 2000], [2000, 2500], [2500, 3000], [3000, 3500], [3500, 4000], [4000, 4500], [4500, 5000], [5000, 5500], [5500, 6000], [6000, 6500], [6500, 7000], [7000, 7500], [7500, 7864]]
>>> list(solve(0, 2000, 500))
[[0, 500], [500, 1000], [1000, 1500], [1500, 2000]]
>>> list(solve(0, 1710, 500))
[[0, 500], [500, 1000], [1000, 1500], [1500, 1710]]
```

Comment: `next if next <=end else end` might be written as `min(next, end)` (which, depending on taste, might be more readable). Also I'd avoid using the identifier `next` since it is a built-in function since python2.6. Use `next_` or `next_elem` instead.